# Something occupy disk storage on ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: disk-usage, disk-management

Am running desktop Ubuntu 22.04. Has 2 physical disks, 1tb + 256.
result of `df` is:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            6155612      4304   6151308   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2 959786032 799864892 111092932  88% /
tmpfs           30778044       844  30777200   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           30778044         0  30778044   0% /run/qemu
/dev/nvme0n1p1    523248      6220    517028   2% /boot/efi
/dev/nvme1n1p1 245023004  28651248 203852488  13% /mnt/8fb1182b-508f-4623-a305-7e89c3c43201
tmpfs            6155608      1716   6153892   1% /run/user/1000
```

**But** `ncdu` executed in `/` tells, that total disk usage is 182gb.
I cant figure out what can occupy 88% of `/`, There is unknown 687gb.

The size now growing *naturally slowly*. Disk usage increased after few unsuccessful attempts to configure cron backup job from `/` to external drive.

Please help analyze this problem.

Comment: Have you rebooted?  Sometimes something might get deleted but stays in reporting on the total used size of the drive as it might still be in use.  A reboot might help clear that out since it should no longer be in use.

Comment: @Terrance rebooted multiple times, seems like its more complex thing

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a lot for us to go off of in your question.  All we can really do is guess.  You could also have a file system problem going on to where you should check it with `fsck` but I would recommend that you run that from a Live USB.  As far as running `ncdu` on the `/` or `root` partition I recommend running it with `sudo` so that it can read into all folders to give you a better view.

Comment: @Terrance the sudo for ncdu is actually solved it - just gonna remove tons of backups inside folder for external drive. I actually thought that it might be fs problem because i running laptop without battery. Thought it is because power loss or smth. Anyway big thank you!